# nodejs push of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, push

```
function seedDB(){
   //Remove all campgrounds
   Campground.remove({}, function(err){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        }
        console.log("removed campgrounds!");
         //add a few campgrounds
        data.forEach(function(seed){
            Campground.create(seed, function(err, campground){
                if(err){
                    console.log(err)
                } else {
                    console.log("added a campground");
                    //create a comment
                    Comment.create(
                        {
                            text: "This place is great, but I wish there was internet",
                            author: "Homer"
                        }, function(err, comment){
                            if(err){
                                console.log(err);
                            } else {
                                **campground.comment.push(comment);**
                                campground.save();
                                console.log("Created new comment");
                            }
                        });
                }
            });
        });
    }); 
    //add a few comments
}

module.exports = seedDB;
```

TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
 can someone help me plz
i don't know what wrong in this function?
why he can't read the property push

Comment: what is `Campground`?

Comment: Suggests using the arrow function for `function(err,comment){...}`. e.g. `(err, comment) -> { }` this is so that it doesn't have its own scope which can hide away`campground`

Comment: @SamuelToh scope is fine here, that's not necessary.

Comment: then the only problem I can see is `campground.comment` is undefined therefore it is erroring when you do `campground.undefined.push`. Maybe try dumping `campground.push`? Make sure it exists

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what Campground is, it will be hard to tell.

Note that when you see the error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'someProperty' of undefined` it's not the property `someProperty` that is undefined, but rather the object that property rests in. In this particular case: `campground.comment`

One thing that comes to my mind is that it seems Comment.create function has a callback as second argument. In that callback, has the comment been created? If the comment isn't created by the time the callback is run then perhaps campground.comment wouldn't exist yet.

Does `campground.save()` need to be invoked before `campground.comment` exists? Try `console.log`'ing your campground object within that callback function `Comment.create`

Perhaps you need to manually set the comment. Something like this:

```
 Comment.create({
    text: "This place is great, but I wish there was internet",
    author: "Homer"
  }, function (err, comment) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      if(campground.comment) {
        campground.comment.push(comment);
      } else {
        campground.comment = [comment];
      }
      campground.save();
      console.log("Created new comment");
    }
  });
```

If your goal was to append comments if there already are some, or create a brand new array with your first comment if there aren't.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 Comment.create(
                         {
                             text: "This place is great, but I wish there was internet",
                             author: "Homer"
                         }, function(err, commenttext){
                             if(err){
                                 console.log(err);
                             } else {
                                 campground.comment.push(commenttext);
                                 campground.save();
                                 console.log("Created new comment");
                             }
                        });
```

if not work ... show me campground model